# Calling controller path /foo/bar/baz results in 404, but is found at default/index.php/foo/bar/baz

Tags: url, controllers, url-rewrite, 404-page

I have set up a simple custom controller based on Alan Storm's tutorial. My controller action should be available on this URL:

http://magento.localhost/helloworld/index/index/

But this path gives a Magento 404 error. The controller is instead found on the following path:

http://magento.localhost/index.php/default/helloworld/index/index/

I don't understand why is this happening, as all of the tutorials and articles I found on the net tell me, that this should be working like that, none of them mention any extra tinkering. This problem is the same for built-in controllers too. This is a base CE 1.7 installation with sample data.

Can anyone shed some light on the matter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have "Show store codes in url" set to "Yes". This explains the need for "default" in the url.
If you cannot access your controller at `http://magento.localhost/default/helloworld/index/index/` it means that your `mod_rewrite` is not enabled or is wrongly configured. This explains the need for `index.php` in the url.

Comment: That is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for - and it is correct! Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

I am on magento 1.8 and i fixed my 404 error by doing the following. inside Magentotutorial_Helloworld.xml they tell you to put this code in

"codePool   local    codePool"

since i do not have a local folder i put mine into the community folder. Change the code to this and it will work.

"codePool  community  codePool"

Comment: Local folder doesn't come by default in a stock Magento installation, you have to manually create it.